# How to do left join two dataframes with varying lengths based on the nearest timestamp in python and not lose any rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I would like to merge two dataframes based on timestamps. The timestamps are not exactly the same in both the dataframes. I want to merge the right dataframe with the left one based on the closest timestamp and have NaN wherever the timestamp is out of the tolerance limit. If i use pandas asof(), i lose all the rows that are out of the tolerance limit.

```
    df_left['timestamp'] = [1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1]
    df_left['value1'] = [10, 20, 30, 10, 30]

    df_right['timestamp'] = [1.05, 2.2, 4.1, 5.12]
    df_right['value2'] = [200, 400, 500, 200]
```

Wanted output:

```
    df_merged['timestamp'] = [1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1]
    df_merged['value1'] = [10, 20, 30, 10, 30]
    df_merged['value2'] = [200, 400, NaN, 500, 200]
```

Comment: In `df_left['value1']` are 6 values, do you think there should be 5 values in sample data?

Comment: yeah, you are right. stupid mistake there., I am sorry. Changed it.

Answer (score 1):

For me working [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) well:

```
df_left = pd.DataFrame()
df_right = pd.DataFrame()
df_left['timestamp'] = [1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1]
df_left['value1'] = [10, 20, 30, 10, 30]

df_right['timestamp'] = [1.05, 2.2, 4.1, 5.12]
df_right['value2'] = [200, 400, 500, 200]

print(df_left)
print(df_right)

df = pd.merge_asof(df_left, df_right, on='timestamp', direction='nearest', tolerance=0.3)
print (df)
   timestamp  value1  value2
0        1.1      10   200.0
1        2.1      20   400.0
2        3.1      30     NaN
3        4.1      10   500.0
4        5.1      30   200.0
```

Comment: Yes; it works. I really don't know where i went wrong. I was trying to use the timestamp index to join them but for some reason it didn't work the way i wanted it to. I changed it to column and it worked. Thanks!